# Hosting a SaaS application on Service Fabric using multiple application instances

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-service-fabric

We would like to host our (multi-tenant) SaaS application on one Service Fabric cluster.  We would host several application instances of one application type on the cluster, one instance for one tenant.  How do we route the tenants to their specific application instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tenant name or identifier as the application instance name. If you need external access, you can use the built-in reverse proxy as a gateway.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the reverse proxy! ;-)